# What causes quadratic hash problem?

Tags: transactions, hash, quadratic-hashing

I read [ScriptSig content during signature (quadratic hashing)](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/54548/scriptsig-content-during-signature-quadratic-hashing) discussing quadratic hash problem.

Quadratic hash problem is the issue that signing (or verifying) transaction time grows with the square of the number of inputs (*O(n^2) where n is the number of inputs*).

Why is that so? I reason the following:

1. For each input you construct different template. **O(n)**
2. This template must be double-SHA-hashed. - **Double-SHA-hash duration is dependent linearly on the size of the template?**
3. Double hashed template (of fixed length) is then signed. - **as the leght is fixed this step is of fixed duration**

As step 2 is dependent linearly on the size of the template, thus it is linearly dependent on the number of inputs, giving final time dependency relation O(n^2)?

More precisely O(n^2+m) where m is the number of outputs (as this contributes in step 2)?

Answer (score 1):

> Double-SHA-hash duration is dependent linearly on the size of the template?

Yes, of course.

So, increasing the count of inputs twice we also increase the size of each template ~twice and the work for signing/verifying whole transaction increased quadratic